# Python3 and Tkinter - How can I check which Notebook Tab is open?

Tags: python, tkinter

my window contains three main widgets, two buttons ("Cancel" and "Export") and a Notebook. The latter has two tabs with others widgets, and both of them must use the same buttons placed in the window. now, keeping in mind what I just wrote, how can I track in which Notebook tab the user are working in order to adapt the button's behaviour to the active tab? in other words, I want to change the "Export" button's behaviour depending on which Notebook tab is used. how can I reach my goal?

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, scrolledtext, filedialog

class MainWindow:

def __init__(self, window):

    ### MAIN WINDOW

    self.window = window
    self.window.title("My Software")
    self.window.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
    self.window.geometry("530x438+360+200")
    self.window.resizable (width=False, height=False)

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("InWhiteFrame.TButton", background="#ffffff", padding = 0)
    style.configure("TButton", padding = 0)
    style.configure("BluText.TLabel", foreground="#99c1e8")
    style.configure("GreyBackground.TLabel", foreground="adadad", background="#e1e1e1", insertbackground="red", fieldbackground= 'blue')

    self.MyNotebook = ttk.Notebook(self.window)
    self.MyNotebook.place(x = 12, y = 12)

    Frame_1 = Frame(self.MyNotebook, background = "#ffffff", width = 506, height = 354, highlightbackground = "#d3d5d9", highlightthickness = 0)
    Frame_1.place(x = 12, y = 12)

    Frame_2 = Frame(self.MyNotebook, background = "#ffffff", width = 506, height = 354, highlightbackground = "#d3d5d9", highlightthickness = 0)
    Frame_2.place(x = 12, y = 12)

    self.MyNotebook.add(Frame_1, text = "Tab 1")
    self.MyNotebook.add(Frame_2, text = "Tab 2")

    self.ExportButton = ttk.Button(self.window, text = "Export", width = 16, command = self.__Save)
    self.ExportButton.place(x = 336, y = 403)
    self.ExportButton.config(state='disable')

    ttk.Button(self.window, text = "Cancel", width = 11, command = self.__Close).place(x = 445, y = 403)

    ### TAB 1

    self.SV1 = StringVar()
    ttk.Label(Frame_1, text = "File 1:", background = "#ffffff").place(x = 16, y = 80)
    self.Entry1 = ttk.Entry(Frame_1, text="", width = 52, textvariable=self.SV1)
    self.Entry1.place(x = 116, y = 80)
    ttk.Button(Frame_1, text="...", width = 4, style = "InWhiteFrame.TButton", command = self.__GetEntry1).place(x = 440, y = 79)

    self.SV2 = StringVar()
    ttk.Label(Frame_1, text = "File 2:", background = "#ffffff").place(x = 16, y = 111)
    self.Entry2 = ttk.Entry(Frame_1, text = "", width = 52, textvariable=self.SV2)
    self.Entry2.place(x = 116, y = 111)
    self.Entry2.config(state='disable')
    self.Entry2Button = ttk.Button(Frame_1, text="...", width = 4, style = "InWhiteFrame.TButton", command = self.__GetEntry2)
    self.Entry2Button.place(x = 440, y = 109)
    self.Entry2Button.config(state='disable')

    self.SV3 = StringVar()
    ttk.Label(Frame_1, text = "File 3:", background = "#ffffff").place(x = 16, y = 218)
    self.Entry3 = ttk.Entry(Frame_1, text = "", width = 52, textvariable=self.SV3)
    self.Entry3.place(x = 116, y = 218)
    self.Entry3.config(state='disable')
    self.Entry3Button = ttk.Button(Frame_1, text="...", width = 4, style = "InWhiteFrame.TButton", command = self.__GetEntry3)
    self.Entry3Button.place(x = 440, y = 217)
    self.Entry3Button.config(state='disable')

    self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.__Close)

    self.SV1.trace("w", self.__Trace)
    self.SV2.trace("w", self.__Trace)
    self.SV3.trace("w", self.__Trace)
    self.window.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.__GetActiveTab)

    ### TAB 2   

    self.LeftSide = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(Frame_2, wrap = WORD, width = 34, height = 11, font = ("Segoe UI", 9))
    self.LeftSide.place(x = 18, y = 42)
    Canvas(Frame_2, width = 207, height = 1, background = "#a0a0a0", highlightthickness = 0).place(x = 18, y = 210)

    RightSide = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(Frame_2, wrap = WORD, width = 34, height = 11, font = ("Segoe UI", 9), state="disable")
    RightSide.place(x = 262, y = 42)
    Canvas(Frame_2, width = 207, height = 1, background = "#a0a0a0", highlightthickness = 0).place(x = 262, y = 210)


    self.SV4 = StringVar()
    self.SV4.set("Option 1")        
    ExportOptions = ttk.Combobox(Frame_2, values = ("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"), state="readonly", textvariable = self.SV4, width = 14)
    ExportOptions.place(x = 93, y = 292)

    self.SV5 = StringVar()
    self.SV5.set("1")
    SaveOptions = ttk.Combobox(Frame_2, values = ("1", "2"), state="readonly", textvariable = self.SV5, width = 8)
    SaveOptions.place(x = 299, y = 292)


def __Trace(self, *args):
    if self.SV1.get() != "":
        self.ExportButton.config(state = "normal")
        self.Entry2.config(state = "normal")
        self.Entry2Button.config(state = "normal")
        self.Entry3.config(state = "normal")
        self.Entry3Button.config(state = "normal")            
        if self.SV2.get() != "":
            self.Entry3.config(state = "disable")
            self.Entry3Button.config(state = "disable")
        elif self.SV3.get() != "":
            self.Entry2.config(state = "disable")
            self.Entry2Button.config(state = "disable")               
    else:
        self.ExportButton.config(state = "disable")            
        self.Entry2.delete(-1, END)    
        self.Entry2.config(state = "disable")
        self.Entry2Button.config(state = "disable")            
        self.Entry3.delete(-1, END)            
        self.Entry3.config(state = "disable") 
        self.Entry3Button.config(state = "disable")


def __GetEntry1(self):
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent = self.window)
    if path != "":
        self.Entry1.delete(-1, END)
        self.Entry1.insert(0, path)

def __GetEntry2(self):
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent = self.window)
    if path != "":
        self.Entry2.delete(-1, END)
        self.Entry2.insert(0, path)

def __GetEntry3(self):
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent = self.window)
    if path != "":
        self.Entry3.delete(-1, END)
        self.Entry3.insert(0, path)

def __GetActiveTab(self, event):
    self.tab = self.MyNotebook.index(self.MyNotebook.select())

def __Save(self):
    print("The user clicked the \"Export\" button in the tab :", self.tab)
    print("It means that I will export the information specified in the tab ", self.tab)

def __Close(self):
    self.window.destroy()


def main():
root = Tk()
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ttk.Notebook` has an event called `<<NotebookTabChanged>>`.

Here is an minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def tab_changed(event):
    print(notebook.select())  # get the instance of tab
    print(notebook.index(notebook.select()))  # get the index of the tab.


root = tk.Tk()

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack()

tab1 = tk.Frame()
notebook.add(tab1, text="tab1")

tab2 = tk.Frame()
notebook.add(tab2, text="tab2")

root.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", tab_changed)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Reference:[ttk document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#notebook)

Comment: Ciao jizhihaoSAMA, it's a good answer but in my code, I need also to track the event and not just to get the information. by default my "Export" button is disable untill the user don't attach a file using another widget placed in the tab 1. now, what about if the "Export" button becames active, and the user changes to the tab 2? when it happens, the Export button should be disable, because, also in this case, you should not go ahead untill you don't attach a file. If I can't track the event (when the tab changes I mean) it's difficult for me implement what I just explained.

Comment: I would very like to use something like the "trace" method for the variables associated to the labels widgets.

Comment: @TurboC Could you show a minimal example of your code?Sorry for my poor English.If you could post your minimal example,I can really understand what do you want to do.

Comment: @ jizhihaoSAMA: sure, I just added a template of my code in my question. as you can see, if you attach the "file 1" in the first tab, the "Export" button becames active, otherwise it remains disabled. now, if you active the "Export" button and then go to the tab 2, the "Export" button should be disabled, because now we are in another tab, and it cannot be enabled untill you don't write something in the lefts crolledtext widget. unfortunately I don't know how to implement the latter part. can you please fix my code keeping in mind what I just wrote?

Comment: @TurboC Why don't consider to use two export button in your example?I think that will be more easy.(Put the button in the `ttk.Notebook`).

Comment: @ jizhihaoSAMA: yeah but it's not what I want to do, I don't like the style of the window with another button. please, can you help me to find a way to reach my goal? if I could track the event, when the tab changes I mean, it would be not so difficult.

Comment: @TurboC Try to use a variable to get the state of the entry `file 1`.And then do some work on the function `def __GetActiveTab(self, event)`.(Judge whether the `self.tab` is `1`).That's an idea.I think that's should be another question.

Comment: @ jizhihaoSAMA: I already tried but to reach my goal I should track the ScrolledText widget too, but it seems that Tkinter can't do it. To solve the issue I will have to keep enable my "Export" button in both tabs, but, .. uff.. It's not what I wanted to do! is it for these stipid limitations that the people prefer to advice PyQT than Tkinter?

Comment: @Turbo Consider to ask a new question,and declare what did you want to do(Before the post,you didn't told us that what does the `scrolledText` do),and post a minimal example.Whatever,tkinter could do it.`Qt` is good but it is enough to do some small project with tkinter.

Comment: @ jizhihaoSAMA: initially I wanted to find a way to track, let me say, in "real time" the events associated to the Notebook widget, exactly as when you use a StringVar to understand if your label is changed or not. unfortunately it's not possible, Tkinter can't do it, but thanks to you I understood how to get the tab index with a function and it can be useful. I'll choose your answer as the solution ;)

Comment: nevertheless, in my last comments I started to speak about the scrolledtext widget, because I thought, if I can't track the tabs in "real time", to reach my goal (disable and enable the "Export" button in the right moments), I could track the main label in the first tab, and the first scrolledtext in the second one, but, also in this case, it's not possible because you can't track a scrolledtext widget, ..

Comment: I didn't ever use PyQt, and from my side Tkinter is a really nice GUI library to be free and already integrated in Python, but now that I'm programming with it since two weeks, I start to see many limitations. in this specific case for example, you can't disable/enable the "Export" button keeping in mind in which tab you are, and neither by considering the event associated to the label widget in the first tab and the scrolled text widget in the second one, because tkinter can't track the neither the Netobook widget nor the Scrolledtext widget.

Comment: So, from my personal experience, it's not true that you can do everithing with Tkinter.

Comment: @TurboC Consider when you want to make the button active.For example, you could bind an event for the `file1` entry, to know whether user select the path(If so, assume `self.state_1 = True`).Then get the index of active tab.If the index is `1`, make the button disabled.Then after user finish the work in the tab 2,we could also do `self.state_2 = True`, which represents the tab need to be active. Could you get it(Apologize for my poor English)?

Comment: @TurboC Yes, I agree with that *it's not true that you can do everithing with Tkinter*.